# Getting 500 Internal server error in restassured when trying to hit an post request

Tags: java, http, postman, rest-assured

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlmlU.png) i am trying to hit post request but getting an 500 internal server error .but in postman can see 200 successful msg.

```java
    @Given("select  POST request")
    public void select_POST_request() {
        RestAssured.baseURI="https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking";
        HashMap<String,String> head=new HashMap<String,String>();
        head.put("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        head.put("Accept", "*/*");
        head.put("Connection", "keep-alive");
        head.put("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        Response resp = RestAssured
                .given()
                .log()
                .all()
                .headers(head)
                .body(body)
                .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
                .when()
                .post();
        System.out.println(resp);
        System.out.println(resp.asPrettyString());
        System.out.println(resp.getStatusCode());
        Assert.assertEquals(resp.getStatusCode(), "200");

    String body="<booking>\r\n"+ "<firstname>guru</firstname>\r\n"              + "<lastname>swa</lastname>\r\n"+ "totalprice>12000</totalprice>\r\n"
+ "<depositpaid>5000</depositpaid>\r\n"+ "<bookingdates>\r\n"+ "<checkin>2023-09-25</checkin>\r\n"+ "checkout>2023-09-27</checkout>\r\n"+ "</bookingdates>\r\n"+ "additionalneeds>lunch</additionalneeds>\r\n"+"</booking>";
```

Comment: You don't have to pay anything for giving an error log.

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify or add details; [edit] your question instead. Post the code that handles the request, and check the server logs fro more information. We need a [mcve] please.

Comment: Console logs has been attached

Comment: I see no console logs here. Links are not sufficient. And I see no server-side logs at all. Unanswerable without that.

Comment: Pls check the attachment and not sure how to take serverside logs

Comment: You get on the server side and find the logs. HTTP 500 deliberately hides all useful information from the client. You will only find the actual error on the server side.

Comment: Actually its an dummy api which i took for practise

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that content you are providing in your request is the same as it is in your postman collection. Variable `body` is not defined in your example. Could it be that it is not serialized correctly? Has some other properties which are not ignored by the back-end service or does not have required ones?

Comment: Json body has been attached